# Yeoman: install dependencies from cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to add an option for when debugging my generator or when working offline that will download npm and bower stuff from cache (by using `--cache-min 999999` and `--offline` respectively).

Currently, this is my code (which both installs the dependencies and calls `grunt bower`):

```
CallumGenerator.prototype.installDeps = function () {
    var cb = this.async();

    this.installDependencies({
        skipInstall: this.options['skip-install'],
        callback: function () {
            this.spawnCommand('grunt', ['bower'])
                .on('close', function () {
                    cb();
                });
        }.bind(this)
    });
};
```

It looks like I'll most likely have to call `.npmInstall()` and `.bowerInstall()` manually in order to specify options (I think?), but I don't know how to specify any options. To clarify, this is how I would do it in the console:

```
npm install --cache-min 999999 --save-dev grunt-contrib-less
bower install --offline --save jquery#1.10.2
```

Comment: Can't you do `this.spawnCommand('bower', ['install', '--offline', '--save jquery#1.10.2'])`?

Comment: Well I could, but I have lots of things to install and I don't particularly want to parse bower.json and package.json manually - there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify options directly from `#installDependencies` see: https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/actions/install.js#L44-L69

You can specify them for both `#npmInstall` and `bowerInstall` https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/master/lib/actions/install.js#L121-L143

The `options` you pass are in the form of an object hash and will be parsed by `dargs` node modules, so you [should follow the module conventions for declaring options](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dargs)

Comment: Thanks. How would I specify the packages in `.npmInstall()`, though? I don't understand what `.installDependencies()` is doing.

Comment: Well, with `#npmInstall`, just pass the package you want to install as an option. `#installDependencies` is just relying on `package.json` and `bower.json` packages declaration (which is IMO the most common use case)

Answer (score 0):

The code I used, which should be fine for anyone to use (you might want to get rid of the final callback, though):

```
CallumGenerator.prototype.installDeps = function () {
    var cb = this.async();

    this.npmInstall(null, {
        skipInstall: this.options['skip-install'],
        cacheMin: this.cachedDeps ? 999999 : 0
    }, function () {
        this.bowerInstall(null, {
            skipInstall: this.options['skip-install'],
            offline: this.cachedDeps
        }, function () {
            this.spawnCommand('grunt', ['bower'])
                .on('close', function () {
                    cb();
                });
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
};
```

It works fine. `this.cachedDeps` will define whether the cache is used or not.